# AppleScript Automation - Bulk uploading files in folder to a single-upload form

Tags: automation, applescript

(First time with AppleScript...) I'm trying to bulk upload files from a local folder to a server via a single-upload form (legacy serverside software behind ddos wall, no control over it)

As I understand:

- I can loop through each file in the filesystem.
- With each file: Invoke "tell" Safari"
- Invoke javascript to "click" a button by ID
- file upload dialog, select the file to upload (?)

I'm having some trouble with syntax in implementing that...

(Also, if that's not the right/best approach, please provide a better one below!)

```
on run  
    tell application "Finder"
        set mlist to (every file of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:username:filestouploadfolder") as alias list

        repeat with this_file in mlist

            tell application "Safari"
                activate

                do JavaScript "document.getElementById('selectToOpenFileDialog').click();" in document 1
                choose file this_file

            end tell
        end repeat

    end tell
    return 0
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacked up a solution though it could probably be more elegant

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        set mfolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:yosun:png:"
        set myFiles to name of every file of folder mfolder
    end tell

    repeat with aFile in myFiles

        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            delay 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('addDeviceTargetUserView').click();" in document 1
            delay 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('targetDimension').value=10;" in document 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('targetImgFile').click();" in document 1


        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
            delay 1
            keystroke "~/png/" & aFile as string
            delay 1
            keystroke return

            delay 1
            keystroke return

            delay 1

        end tell

        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            delay 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('AddDeviceTargetBtn').click();" in document 1
        end tell

        delay 10

    end repeat
end run
```